# Xamarin Forms: How to capture the webview video/audio play time?

Tags: video, xamarin.forms, webview

I am using webview for playing video and audio in my projects like the below screenshot.

[image]

I need to capture the video/audio playtime when going back from that page. I research about this but didn't get anything useful.

Is there any way to fetch the video/audio playtime?

**Update**

**Video: XAML**

```
<local:VideoWebview
    x:Name="web_view"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
</local:VideoWebview>
```

**XAML.CS**

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    web_view.Url = videourl;
});
}
else
{
    web_view.Source = videourl;
}
```

**Audio: XAML**

```
<WebView 
    x:Name="web_view"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
</WebView>
```

**XAML.CS**

```
web_view.Source = audiourl;
```

Sample Video URL: https://player.vimeo.com/video/434126696?api=1&player_id=player1

Sample Audio URL: http://catholic-brain.s3.amazonaws.com/qa/dc/cbrain-app/files/doc-lib/2017/08/16/11/21/59/604/head/Catholic-brain-01-The-Rosary-Song.mp3

I am using a custom renderer in ios video webview for the transparent background.

```
public class VideoWebviewRenderer : ViewRenderer<VideoWebview, WKWebView>
{
    WKWebView wkWebView;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<VideoWebview> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            WKWebViewConfiguration configuration = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
            configuration.AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
            wkWebView = new WKWebView(CGRect.Empty, configuration);
            //transparent background
            wkWebView = new WKWebView(CGRect.Empty, configuration);
            wkWebView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            wkWebView.ScrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            wkWebView.Opaque = false;

            if (Element.Url != null)
            {
                wkWebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl((Element).Url)));
            }
            SetNativeControl(wkWebView);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName.Equals(nameof(Element.Url)))
        {
            wkWebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl((Element).Url)));
        }
    }

    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);

        Control.Frame = rect;
    }
}
```

**Update1**

@Pete  I have tried the `MediaElement` but the video or audio is not displaying on the UI.

I have done a sample and uploaded it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JiBAtx0O_6Bk4aRXSKKkycbMCtZF7d0f/view?usp=sharing), could you please check what I am missing?

And I didn't get the first step, how I can create a stream for my Vimeo videos? For audio files, do I need to create the stream? Could you please explain the audio part implementation? I have added the audio part in the sample, it is not visible on UI, but I can hear the audio.

Sample Video URL: https://player.vimeo.com/video/434126696?api=1&player_id=player1

Sample Audio URL: http://catholic-brain.s3.amazonaws.com/qa/dc/cbrain-app/files/doc-lib/2017/08/16/11/21/59/604/head/Catholic-brain-01-The-Rosary-Song.mp3

**My Vimeo videos have no extension like .mp4**

**Update2**

So before playing a video, we need to download the configurations of the video. I have a look at the configurations and there are 5 different configurations. So we need to take the value of URL from the progressive list, right?

[image]

Comment: Hi, whether the source of video/audio is an url? And you can share some code about 
that page how playing video/audio by webview.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I have edited the question with some code, could you please have a look?

Comment: Thanks for updating , I will check that.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't extract **time** from a tab playing an audio file or from embedded video (_eg: Youtube or Vime._), You must talk to the decoder via JavaScript to know the decoded playback time. It won't be possible the way you're doing it (just opening a link via `webView`).  You could try making custom html in a `HtmlWebViewSource` where the html creates an `<audio>` tag for mp3 or embeds the Vimeo player. The html should also have Javascript to echo the time via relevant methods (eg:  using `audio.currentTime` if audio tag, or Vimeo API's own command for time extract).

Comment: @VC.One Is there any way to detect the play/pause button of video/audio is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an answer how to do this using **Xamarin.Forms**, as you mentioned in a comment if there was any alternative player offering to fetch playtime, so here goes:-

To do this in **Xamarin.Forms** you can use the **MediaElement** that was introduced in **Xamarin.Forms 4.5**.

To do so, there are a couple things you need to do:-

1. Determine a stream to play from the video configuration stored on **Vimeo**.

You can get this configuration by inspecting the **JSON** that is returned from the below url:-

`http://player.vimeo.com/video/36671239/config`

i.e., where **36671239** is your **Video ID** on **Vimeo**.

Below is an example of one of stream, which is in **mp4** video format:-

`https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1597882056~acl=%2A%2F84157673.mp4%2A~hmac=1230da01c045577d047b307a0d3679b46cc9b0bbc1d0312e272b67bb31d5129c/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/2334/1/36671239/84157673.mp4`

2. **Very Important**:-

The **MediaElement** is in **Preview Release**, and if you don't do the following upon application start-up you will almost always receive **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException** being thrown with it crashing and you will be puzzled for a while.

To avoid this add the following for the time being in the App() constructor:-

`Device.SetFlags(new[] { "MediaElement_Experimental" });`

3. The **MediaElement** doesn't issue **PropertyChanged** notifications for the **Position** property, at present.

To get around this however, you can use your own **Timer**, and retrieve the **Position** property of the video that is exposed, and use that however.

This is by no means fit for production, as you wouldn't want the timer always running, but is to just illustrate that you can achieve what you want:-

Set up an active timer in the constructor like so:-

`Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), () =>
{
    if (videoPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
    {
        string strPlayPosition = videoPlayer.Position.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        lblCurrentVideoTime.Text = strPlayPosition;
    }
    return true;
});`

4. Add the following on the **ContentPage**:-

`<Grid BackgroundColor="#242475">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <MediaElement
    x:Name="videoPlayer"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Aspect="AspectFit"
    BackgroundColor="Black"
    ShowsPlaybackControls="True"
    Source="https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1597882056~acl=%2A%2F84157673.mp4%2A~hmac=1230da01c045577d047b307a0d3679b46cc9b0bbc1d0312e272b67bb31d5129c/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/2334/1/36671239/84157673.mp4" />

  <StackLayout
    Grid.Row="1"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    VerticalOptions="Center">

    <Label
      FontAttributes="Bold"
      FontSize="18"
      Text="CURRENT VIDEO TIME : "
      TextColor="White" />
    <Label
      x:Name="lblCurrentVideoTime"
      FontAttributes="Bold"
      FontSize="18"
      TextColor="White" />

  </StackLayout>

</Grid>


and you will see something like the following, with whatever video you would like to watch from Vimeo:-
The MediaElement can also be used on audio as well.

Update 1
I've taken a look at your video id you mentioned (434126696).
and there are multiple mp4 streams that are specified in the configuration.
One such stream is:-

https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1598157872~acl=%2Fvimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us%2F01%2F1825%2F17%2F434126696%2F1890592390.mp4~hmac=a0ac67f23fdd68df9d16fb2db33e8b2b00d0dc3626375d2a4c6ba7a5203b935e/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/1825/17/434126696/1890592390.mp4

if you place this mp4 link in the MediaElement, in my example, like so:-

  <MediaElement
    x:Name="videoPlayer"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Aspect="AspectFit"
    BackgroundColor="Black"
    ShowsPlaybackControls="True"
    Source="https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1598157872~acl=%2Fvimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us%2F01%2F1825%2F17%2F434126696%2F1890592390.mp4~hmac=a0ac67f23fdd68df9d16fb2db33e8b2b00d0dc3626375d2a4c6ba7a5203b935e/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/1825/17/434126696/1890592390.mp4" />


You will see your video playing.
You have to analyze the JSON returned.  In C# you can download the configuration like so:-

using (var objClient = new WebClient())
{
string strResponse = objClient.DownloadString("http://player.vimeo.com/video/434126696/config");
}`

Then if you use the **JSON** inspector, you will be able to see the various **mp4** streams that are exposed for your video at different resolutions.  You can then pick a suitable one that you want to display your video using.

Comment: Pete I have tried the `MediaElement`, but facing some issues. I have updated the details on the question, could you please have a look? Thanks

Comment: I have completed the audio part, but the video is not playing.

Comment: @SreejithSree i've updated my answer.  There are mp4 streams exposed but you need to analyze and extract the appropriate one you want to display.  See my answer update for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you please have a look at the update 2 section in the question?

Comment: @SreejithSree There was about 5 or 6 streams with different quality resolutions from what I remember.  So long as the url is mp4 then it should be ok.  I didn't inspect the full JSON looking for all possibilities.  It would be a matter of taking a few videos, check if a method of extraction worked that was consistent across multiple videos and then write some code to automatically perform the extraction and return either all or a specific stream quality, depending on your device where you are wanting to play the video on / internet streaming speed available.  HTH

Comment: I will write some code to perform the extraction, thank you very much

Comment: I am facing a weird issue now. I am playing a video using mediaelement. When I click back button from that page, going back is not working. If I tap multiple times, then only previous page is showing on the UI.

Comment: I am pasing the video when click back button, `videoPlayer.Pause();`, but multiple taps requires to go back

Comment: I have a weird issue related to MediaElement, could you please have a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63762912/xamarin-forms-native-crash-reporting-in-ios-platform-due-to-mediaelement-featur

Answer (score 2):

**Unfortunately**, I have tested in local site from shared source link, but can not get the play time.

> Video URL:  https://player.vimeo.com/video/434126696?api=1&player_id=player1

The video url is a wrapped player link. We need the player to expose the javascript api of play time. Then we can invoke that in Native code.

> Audio URL: http://catholic-brain.s3.amazonaws.com/qa/dc/cbrain-app/files/doc-lib/2017/08/16/11/21/59/604/head/Catholic-brain-01-The-Rosary-Song.mp3

The audio url is a original source(.mp3), we only can get the duration time of it.

```
NSString url = new NSString("xxx.mp3");

if (url.PathExtension == new NSString("mp3"))
{

    NSUrl videoUrl = new NSUrl(url.ToString());

    AVUrlAsset avUrl = new AVUrlAsset(videoUrl, new NSDictionary(AVUrlAsset.PreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey, true));

    CMTime time = avUrl.Duration;

    float seconds = time.Value / time.TimeScale;

    Console.WriteLine("====================" + seconds );
}
```

If need to get the play time , you also can use a wrapped audio player. And also expose its javascript api of play time.

**Generally**, if use `audio` and `video` property of **Html** to play *original source url* , we can invoke js to get their `currentTime` and `duration` in iOS as follow:

```
//video
string JsStr = "(document.getElementsByTagName(\"video\")[0]).currentTime";
// audio
//string JsStr = "(document.getElementsByTagName(\"audio\")[0]).currentTime";

WKJavascriptEvaluationResult handler = (NSObject result, NSError err) =>
{
    if (err != null)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("================"+err);
    }
    if (result != null)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("currentTime is : "+result);
    }
};
wkWebView.EvaluateJavaScript(JsStr, handler);
```

Comment: Is there any way to call an event when the play/pause button of video/audio is pressed? If yes, we can start a stopwatch when the play button of video/audio is pressed. When pause we can stop the stopwatch and find out the playtime.

Comment: what about implementing a video/audio(vimeo video) player? Suggest me the best player having the option to fetch playtime?

Comment: @SreejithSree - you can use Xamarin.Forms MediaElement to achieve this, see my answer for more details

Comment: @SreejithSree `video/audio` is the property in `Html` , such as: `<video preload="none" tabindex="-1" style="" src="blob:https://player.vimeo.com/f925b0d1-642f-4105-bf96-e4a2878e8a6c"></video>`

Comment: @SreejithSree Due to using the web player to play video inside webview, if player expose the api that will be the best option. Otherwise you can use custom local html to play video and audio .

Answer (score 1):

Code for performing the JSON extraction:

```
public  void ExtractConfiguration(string vimeoUrl)
{
    try
    {
        using (var objClient = new WebClient())
        {
            string strResponse = objClient.DownloadString(vimeoUrl);
            VimeoConfig vimeoConfig = new VimeoConfig();
            vimeoConfig = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VimeoConfig>(strResponse.ToString());
            string url = vimeoConfig.request.files.progressive[0].url;
            videoPlayer.Source = url;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>"+e);
    }
}

//Model

public class VimeoConfig
{
    public Request request { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public Files files { get; set; }
}

public class Files
{
    public List<Progressive> progressive { get; set; }
}

public class Progressive
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```