# Xamarin Forms: Issue with MediaElement audio playing

Tags: xamarin.forms, mediaelement

I am using `MediaElement` for playing audio. I have a list of items and I need to play audio one after another. When playing audio I will change the background color of that list item. Also If I tap an item, the audio of that selected item starts playing, also the color of that item is modifying. These features are working fine in android. I have added a video of the android [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14iGg3Ubs2zbcFPLjvfPssFNH1vbC6PkN/view?usp=sharing).

Because of [Native Crash Reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63762912/xamarin-forms-native-crash-reporting-in-ios-platform-due-to-mediaelement-featur) of `MediaElement`, I have added a [custom renderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/MediaElementRenderer.cs) in the ios platform. After adding the custom renderer, there are some issues while playing audio in ios. After playing the first audio, the second and third items background color is modifying. After that, the next 2 items color is modifying. I need to play items one by one.

My code:

```
//Xaml
<MediaElement 
    x:Name="audio_mediaelement"
    MediaEnded="AudioEnded"
    ShowsPlaybackControls="True">
    <MediaElement.HeightRequest>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <OnIdiom.Phone>80</OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnIdiom.Tablet>120</OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnIdiom.Desktop>80</OnIdiom.Desktop>
        </OnIdiom>
    </MediaElement.HeightRequest>
</MediaElement>

//Initial audio source set up
audio_mediaelement.Source = aduiourl

//When audio end 
public void AudioEnded(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    audioOrder = audioOrder + 1;
    if(audioOrder < listVerses.Count)
    {
        audio_mediaelement.Source = aduioFormat + listVerses[audioOrder].audioUrl;
        ChapterList.ItemsSource = listVerses;
        listVerses[audioOrder].BGColor = Color.FromHex("#f2ee71");
        ChapterList.ScrollTo(((IList)ChapterList.ItemsSource)[audioOrder-1], ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
    }
}
```

I have uploaded a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qoDjyeGyORC40yY4HGaj57hEfSkQ3FYN/view?usp=sharing) for reference since it is very difficult to understand the issue without a sample. If I didn't add the `MediaElement` custom renderer, the app will hang after playing audio.

Comment: Make sure that you had removed all personal information from the sample (like personal IP address and password) . You could use static data .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Updated sample project with static data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the **AutoPlay** as False in default and play the video manually .

```
<MediaElement 
     HeightRequest="400"
     AutoPlay="False"
     x:Name="media"
     MediaEnded="AudioEnded"
     ShowsPlaybackControls="True">
                
</MediaElement>
```

#### in Code behind

Play the video after setting the url

```
media.Source = xxx;
media.Play();
```

And when want to play the next video

```
public void AudioEnded(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   media.Stop();
   media.Source = new url;
   media.Play();
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but no change. I am trying to play audio, not video.

Comment: They are the same , I could not test your sample as it contains personal url .

Comment: Sample without personal url, Could you please check? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qoDjyeGyORC40yY4HGaj57hEfSkQ3FYN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It works fine on my side . Maybe the issue is caused by the network environment .

Comment: Issue is on the ios platform, in android it is working fine. Please watch this video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WT-5RGt3-X_NMtd-iNDh-WsTxoyC3R2R/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems work fine with playing one by one .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225977/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).