# Unable to capture audio from webview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Forms app that needs to capture audio from a webview. I have the following set in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUDIO_CAPTURE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.low_latency" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.pro" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.resource.AUDIO_CAPTURE" />
```

I have the following in the android webview custom renderer

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    Control.Download += OnDownload;
    Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    Control.Settings.SetGeolocationEnabled(true);
    Control.Settings.SetGeolocationDatabasePath(Control.Context.FilesDir.Path);

    Control.Settings.SetSupportZoom(false);
    Control.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
    Control.Settings.AllowContentAccess =true;
    Control.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
    Control.Settings.SetPluginState(Android.Webkit.WebSettings.PluginState.On);

    if (e.OldElement == null)
    {
        ResetCookieManagerSettings();
        var chromeClient = new ArenaWebChromeClient((uploadMsg, acceptType, capture) =>
        {
            var webViewClient = new WebViewClient(this);
            if (App.Self.IsConnected)
            {
                Control.SetWebChromeClient(chromeClient);
                webViewClient.PageLoadStarted += RaiseLoadStarted;
                webViewClient.PageLoadFinished += RaiseLoadFinished;
                Control.SetWebViewClient(webViewClient);
          }
          else
          {
              webViewClient.PageLoadStarted -= RaiseLoadStarted;
              webViewClient.PageLoadFinished -= RaiseLoadFinished;
          }
     }
}
```

This is all fine. My Chrome code for checking the permissions is this

```
    public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)
    {
        base.OnPermissionRequest(request);
        if (request != null)
        {
            permissionRequest = request;
            var res = request.GetResources();
            if (res.Length != 0)
            {
                foreach(var r in res)
                {
                    if (r.Contains("AUDIO_CAPTURE"))
                    {
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                        {
                            var perms = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Media>();
                            if (perms != Xamarin.Essentials.PermissionStatus.Granted)
                            {
                                var request = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Media>();
                                if (request == Xamarin.Essentials.PermissionStatus.Granted)
                                {
                                    var mod = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();
                                    if (mod != Xamarin.Essentials.PermissionStatus.Granted)
                                    {
                                        var t = await Xamarin.Essentials.PermissionRequestAsync<Permissions.Media>();

#if DEBUG
                                        Console.WriteLine("Microphone set");
#endif
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var mod = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();
                                if (mod != Xamarin.Essentials.PermissionStatus.Granted)
                                {
                                    var t = await Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Media>();

#if DEBUG
                                    Console.WriteLine("Microphone set");
#endif
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }               
        }
    }
```

This all works. However. when I try to record via the webview, I'm getting the following error.

```
chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(76)] "The following error occurred: NotAllowedError: Permission denied", source: https://mywebsite/myurl (76)
```

I'm not sure if it's on the server side or app side as when the user on the website tries to record, a recording is made.

Comment: You can check this thread first:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63480072/xamarin-forms-how-to-capture-the-webview-video-audio-play-time

Comment: This is fine for playing, but not capture